# How can I have the magic `__contains__` method invoked?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the contains method in my Sentence class that checks if a word is in a sentence(string in my case)

I tried to check in my `functionTesting` if `hello` exist in `hello world` and I got this error instead:

```
AttributeError: 'Sentence' object has no attribute 'contains'
```

here is my code

```
class Sentence:

    def __init__(self, string):
        self._string = string

    def getSentence(self):
        return self._string

    def getWords(self):
        return self._string.split()

    def getLength(self):
        return len(self._string)

    def getNumWords(self):
        return len(self._string.split())

    def capitalize(self):
        self._string = self._string.upper()

    def punctation(self):
        self._string = self._string + ", "

    def __str__(self):
        return self._string

    def __getitem__(self, k):
        return k

    def __len__(self):
        return self._String

    def __getslice__(self, start, end):
        return self[max(0, i):max(0, j):]

    def __add__(self, other):
        self._string = self._string + other._string
        return self._string

    def __frequencyTable__(self):
        return 0

    def __contains__(self, word):
        if word in self._string:
            return True  # contains function!!##


def functionTesting():
    hippo = Sentence("hello world")
    print(hippo.getSentence())
    print(hippo.getLength())
    print(hippo.getNumWords())
    print(hippo.getWords())

    hippo.capitalize()
    hippo.punctation()

    print(hippo.getSentence())

    print(hippo.contains("hello"))


functionTesting()
```

How do you call the `__contains__` function? Did I make a mistake in the class method function or did I make a mistake in the `functionTesting` when calling it? I am expecting to get `True`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Quoting the documentation of [`__contains__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__),

> Called to implement membership test operators. Should return true if **`item` is in `self`**, false otherwise. For mapping objects, this should consider the keys of the mapping rather than the values or the key-item pairs.
>
> For objects that don’t define `__contains__()`, the membership test first tries iteration via `__iter__()`, then the old sequence iteration protocol via `__getitem__()`

So, it will be invoked when used with the membership testing operator, `in`, and you should use it like this

```
print("hello" in hippo)
```

**Important Note:** Python 3.x, doesn't have `__getslice__` special method at all. Quoting [Python 3.0 Change log](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#operators-and-special-methods),

> `__getslice__()`, `__setslice__()` and `__delslice__()` were killed. The syntax `a[i:j]` now translates to `a.__getitem__(slice(i, j))` (or `__setitem__()` or `__delitem__()`, when used as an assignment or deletion target, respectively).

So, you cannot invoke it with the slicing syntax.

---

> I am expecting to get True.

No. You cannot get `True`, because you already called `hippo.capitalize()` before the membership test. So, your `self._string` is `HELLO WORLD,`  by the time membership test is happening. So, you will actually get `False`.

**Note 1:** In Python, boolean values are represented with `True` and `False`. But in your `__contains__` function you are returning `true` which will raise `NameError` at runtime. You can better write it succinctly like this

```
def __contains__(self, word):
    return word in self._string
```

**Note 2:** Also in your `__getslice__` function,

```
def __getslice__(self, start, end):
    return self[max(0, i):max(0, j):]
```

you are using `i` and `j` which are not defined. Perhaps you wanted to use `start` and `end` like this

```
def __getslice__(self, start, end):
    return self[max(0, start):max(0, end):]
```

Comment: You are right about Note 2. Have not debugged those functions yet. Thank you

Comment: Note: if the OP is really using python3 then `__getslice__` is useless because it was removed. It should be implemented inside `__getitem__` by checking that the index is a `slice` object. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=special%20methods#specialnames) for the list of python3 special methods.

Comment: @Bakuriu Thanks :-) I included that as an important note and the change log reference in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can call the `__contains__` function by using `in` keyword

like

```
print "hello" in hippo
```